# fire input onchange event after click on button tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am doing calculation with function ("update_total") by "onchange" event of input tab number.
it is working fine. no any issue.

when i am using  jquery plugin "Nice-Number" for showing plus(+), minus(-) button.
(https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Number-Input-Spinner-jQuery-Nice-Number.html)

onchange event of input tag is not getting fire. because mouse get clicked on plus(+) or minus(-) button.

therefor i am not getting ("update_total") total value.

please help  how to resolve this issue.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="number"]').niceNumber();
});

function update_total(spineerid, product_price, totalid) {
  spineerid = '#' + spineerid;
  totalid = '#' + totalid;

  var qty_count = $(spineerid).val();
  var total = product_price * qty_count;
  $(totalid).html(total + '/-'); // display total 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.nice-number@2.1.0/src/jquery.nice-number.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.nice-number@2.1.0/src/jquery.nice-number.js"></script>


<div class="card" style="width:12rem">
  <div class="card-header">
    <?php echo $row['product_name'] ?>
  </div>
  <img src="product-images/<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="150px">
  <div>
    <span> &#8377;<?php echo$row['product_price']?> </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" min="1" value="1" name="spinnerNumber<?php echo $row['product_id']?>" id="spinnerNumber<?php echo $row['product_id']?>" onchange="update_total('spinnerNumber<?php echo $row['product_id']?>','<?php echo$row['product_price']?>','total<?php echo $row['product_id']?>')">
  </div>

  <div class="card-footer">
    <!-- Total -->
    <div>
      Total: &#8377; <span id="total<?php echo $row['product_id']?>">0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you the snippet. Please CHANGE all PHP variables to HTML attributes so we can see a [mcve] you could have made from the start. I want to see 3 rows

Comment: You can use Nice Number Callback function *onDecrement* & *onIncrement* to  trigger input *change* event manually using pure javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change:

```
onchange="update_total...
```

by oninput

```
oninput="update_total...
```

```js
$('input[type="number"]').niceNumber();


function update_total(spineerid, product_price, totalid) {
  spineerid = '#' + spineerid;
  totalid = '#' + totalid;

  var qty_count = $(spineerid).val();
  var total = product_price * qty_count; 
  $(totalid).html(total + '/-'); // display total 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.nice-number@2.1.0/src/jquery.nice-number.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.nice-number@2.1.0/src/jquery.nice-number.js"></script>

<div class="card" style="width:12rem">
    <div class="card-header">Product1</div>
    <img src="product-images/image1" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="150px">
    <div>
        <span>100</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="spinnerNumberProduct1"
            id="spinnerNumberProduct1"
            oninput="update_total('spinnerNumberProduct1','100','totalProduct1')">
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
        <!-- Total -->
        <div>
            Total: <span id="totalProduct1">0</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i have just changed min="0" and value="0" to have a correct initialization

Answer (score 0):

You need to make following two changes:-

1. Attach data attributes to the input fields so that you can access the values in the callbacks.
2. You need to pass the `onDecrement` & `onIncrement` callbacks in `niceNumber()`

Please find the changes below:-

`

```
<input 
   data-productid="<?php echo $row['product_id']?>"
   data-productprice="<?php echo$row['product_price']?>"
   type="number" min="1" value="1" name="spinnerNumber<?php echo $row['product_id']?>"
   id="spinnerNumber<?php echo $row['product_id']?>">
```

`

`

```
<script>   
   $(function() {
       $('input[type="number"]').niceNumber({
           onDecrement:  function ($currentInput, amount, settings) {
               // Extract out data attributes from $currentInput
               // Do your required calculations
           },
           onIncrement:  function ($currentInput, amount, settings) {
                // Extract out data attributes from $currentInput
               // Do your required calculations
           }
       });
   });
</script>
```

`